# How can I see my actual directory in my bash prompt?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, anaconda, prompt

I installed bash in my Anaconda prompt, and this is what I'm seeing:

`bash-4.3$`

and I would like to see something like:

`zzzz@zzvdhdc/users/xxx/myactualdirectory`

Answer (score 1):

use `\w` for the current directory:

```
PS1='\w $'
```

see `man bash` for more options to change your promt.